# required in jqueryValidate after press return keyboard

Tags: jquery, forms, jquery-validate

i have a textfield required, press return on keyboard and i have class error (in my css, right behavior) .

If i insert text and then press return key, the form submit but the textfield return with class error again

in my javascript i use this for clear my form

```
$("#formid")[0].reset();
```

**More code**

```
<form method="post"  id="form_commento-3" class="form_fancybox_commenti">
    <span style="position: relative">
       <input type="text" id="commento_form_3_commento" name="commento_form_3[commento]" required="required" maxlength="100"    class="small" placeholder="comment..." />
    </span>
    <button type="submit" class="submit-button" id="submit_form_commenti">Comment</button>
 </form>
```

**More**
The form is very similar at [jQuery Validate within jQuery .each()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19046077/jquery-validate-within-jquery-each)

My js:

```
$('.form_fancybox_commenti').each(function(index, numero_form) {

    $("#commento_form_"+index+"_commento").addClass("alphanumeric");

    $(this).validate({
        submitHandler: function(form) {
            console.log("form "+form);
            save(form);

        }
    });
});

function save(form) {
    var parametri = {};
    parametri = $("#" + form.id).serializeArray();

    //    i try with
    //$("#" + form.id)[0].reset();
    //$("#form_commento-"+id).trigger('reset')
    //$("#form_commento-"+id).get(0).reset();


save via node.js

}
```

This behavior is

- properly fill the text field
- press return key
- form submit and my textfield is ok

if

- not fill properly the text field (error jquery validate)
- fix the textfield and press return key
- form submit and my textfield return with class error again

Thanks

Comment: Show enough code for a complete working demo.

Comment: Don't you think the _rendered_ HTML of the form would be more useful in the context of a JavaScript question?

Comment: @sparky I added some information